# A word for an individuals divergence from the tribe/family/cell-group to begin a new “X”

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word for a mans journey of leaving home to gain experience and start a family of his own and/or return to the village with wisdom and riches.

There certainly is culural words that apply here but also maybe there is a biology term that would aptly fit in this context.

Comment: In fairy tales that's called "setting off to seek his fortune."  Anyway, for your question to be on-topic you need to show us what your sentence would look like, with a blank in the place where the sought word would go.

Comment: Example sentence please. It's required for a single-word-request.

Answer (score 0):

How about "quest"?

“You don’t receive wisdom; we must discover it for ourselves after a quest that no one can take for us or spare us.” ~ Marcel Proust